# A java bug I need help fixing

Tags: java

So i'm working on a text game and i'm having a bug pop up. For short when i'm running the program it does this.

```
    Channel name:
    hey
    Your channel name, hey, are you sure you like this name? type yes or no.
    no
    Name for video?
```

What I want to happen is when someone says no it restarts the program, but the program continues anyways. Heres the code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //views


    //channel name
    String cfc = "Channel name: ";
    System.out.println(cfc);
    String cn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your channel name, " + cn + ", are you sure you like this name? type yes or no.");
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Boolean nn;
    String yn;
    while (true) {
        yn = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
        if (yn.equals("yes")) {
            nn = true;
            break;
        } else if (yn.equals("no")) {
            nn = false;
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Channel name: ");
            System.out.println(cfc);
            String un = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Your channel name, " + un + ", are you sure you like this name? type yes or no.");
        }
    }
    Video();
}
```

I don't know whats the problem. Please help.

Comment: You wrote "when someone says no it restarts the program" - did you mean: "exit the program" ?

Comment: `break` is breaking out of the loop...consider using an actual "real" exit cause to your loop...

Comment: I want it to reset so it will repeat the beginning line "Channel name: " so then you input what your name will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` is breaking you of your loop, so when you enter `no`, you are breaking out of the loop and running in the `video` method...

Instead, don't be lazy and use an actual real exit condition to your loop.  Also, you want to run this loop at least once, so `do-while` loop instead, this will ensure that the loop must run at least one...

Also, you will want to move the prompt into the loop, so it is repeated, otherwise it's likely not to make sense to the user, for example...

```
boolean nn = false;
String cfc = "Channel name: ";
String cn = null;
do {
    System.out.println(cfc);
    cn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your channel name, " + cn + ", are you sure you like this name? type yes or no.");
    yn = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
    if (yn.equals("yes")) {
        nn = true;
    }
} while (!nn);
```

Comment: I'll check and see if this will work. Again i'm only a beginner.

Comment: Goto start somewhere...take a look at [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details

Comment: I think your code is redundant and I can say that it is wrong.. what would happen if you typed "no"?

Comment: I thought you where a little harsh.

Comment: There is a extra line of code that does not need to be there. On the else if statment you typed "System.out.println("Channel name: ");" Then typed "System.out.println(cfc);" Those both do the same thing.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The line "Instead, don't be lazy and use an actual real exit condition to your loop," that sounded a bit harsh at that.

Comment: @RainShadowMan Yep, I've updated the code a little, was to busy trying to get the idea across, missed the implementation ;)

Comment: @RainShadowMan Yep, it kind of is, because using `while (true)` is just that, sorry, but it's lazy and causes no end of issues, not just with controlling the loop but also in the readability of the code. I'm old school, I was taught to have one entry, one exit.  Your code had two exit options, while it's only a short set of statements, imagine if it run for more the one screen, it's real easy to miss those and end up scratching your head, nothing personal to you

Comment: The code you did type worked for me so i'm good. Anyways I'll see you around.

Comment: @MadProgrammer K, I understand. I'm currently 138 pages in Java for Dummies All-in-one, book. I close to where it talks about looping.

Comment: @RainShadowMan Keep going!  It will get easier the more do ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to `continue` instead of `break`.

Answer (score 1):

Using do-while loop would be better.
Also, the else-if and else part in below code might be redundant.

```
boolean nn = false;
String cfc = "Channel name: ";
String cn = null;
do {
    System.out.println(cfc);
    cn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your channel name, " + cn + ", are you sure you like this name? type yes or no.");
    yn = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
    if (yn.equals("yes")) {
        nn = true;
    } else if (yn.equals("no")) {
        System.out.println("Channel name: "); // Possibly duplicated?            
    } else {
        //Handle cases that yn not equals to "yes" or "no"
    }
} while (!nn);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some redundant code snippets there, I think you can do something like this:

```
String cfc = "Channel name: ";
String cn;
boolean nn = false;
String yn;

while (!nn) {
    System.out.println(cfc);
    cn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your channel name, " + cn + ", are you sure you like this name? type yes or no.");
    yn = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
    if (yn.equals("yes")) {
        nn = true;
    } else {
        nn = false;
    }
}
```

Obviously you didn't use `nn` before, which is quite strange. I believe you declare it to be used, right? And one pair of `if-else` is enough to achieve what you want.

Comment: I am sorry, may you elaborate?